# How to resolve Git error: "Couldn't create temporary repository"

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin

I am extremely new to the concept of Git. I installed the Git plugin for Eclipse and I'm now trying to clone a one year old Eclipse project.

First, I was getting an error saying:

```
Cannot list the available branches.
Reason-Exception caught during execution of ls-remote command.
```

I solved that by doing some ssh-related property changes.

Now I am getting an error saying,

```
Couldn't create temporary repository.
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. Are you trying to do this on a remote machine or your local machine?

Comment: I am doing this on my local machine.

Comment: Hi Michael,
Which location is used by default to create a repo?
Can we change this repository location manually?

Comment: That is going to depend on your configuration. Are you using EGit? What is your OS? If you are cloning a remote project using EGit you can [select the location for your working copy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Local_Destination).

Comment: Yes I am using Egit, and  OS is Windows 7.
Selecting a master a node is a step after the creation of repository , right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you cloning an existing git repository or are you trying to create a local git repository from scratch?

Comment: I am simply trying to use existing project
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Lyo/BuildTestSuite#Prerequisites
I am following above link to clone my repo with eclipse lyo project.

Comment: In that case you set the destination to create the repository in the Local Destination page. From the guide you linked: "On the Local Destination page, specify a location or accept the default and click Finish." The default location should also be listed there. I would make sure the location is inside the Users folder for your account.

Comment: I am not even able to reach that step.As soon as I hit next button after entering a URl as shown in very first slide I am getting the mentioned error.

Comment: I too get the same error, looking forward for some replies..

Comment: I have this issue only on macOS (currently Eclipse Neon & macOS Sierra)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are on windows: Try to delete file *C:/Documents and Settings/[username]/.gitconfig*.

Comment: Why, should he do that?

Comment: ? BuZZ-dEE At some point in time I had the same problem. I looked all over the net and tried various things. This worked for me at that point in time. Since then there were several upgrades to the eclipse.

Comment: This worked for me, although the path is different (C:\Users\\[username]\.gitconfig)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some suggestion in the [Eclipse forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/530714/) that the version of EGit you are using might be outdated. Try updating to a more recent version of EGit.

The address for the latest EGit build is:

> http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

You can find directions for installing adding the software site [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=//org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-127.htm).

Comment: this actually helped me in Eclipse Neon and macOs Sierra, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in Windows, run the eclipse as administrator. (Tried and worked)
If you are in Linux or Mac, open the eclipse with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Note that gitconfig can come from different places in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17756808/5150013) order

If anyone faced the same issue, what fixed it for me is to have a .gitconfig in the home directory with the name and email entries like so:

```
[http]
    sslVerify = false
[user]
    name = name-in-git
    email = email-in-git@email.com
```

PS: sslVerify is false due to self-signed certs in my case