# Setting WinMerge as diff viewer

Tags: git

I have set up my `.gitconfig` to the following values:

```
[diff]
    guitool = winmerge
[difftool "winmerge"]
    cmd = winmergeu.exe -e -ub -x -wl -u -maximise -dl "base" -dr "mine" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[difftool]
        prompt = false
```

But when I `git config --list --global` the settings are:

```
difftool.winmerge.path=c:/Program Files (x86)/winmerge/winmergeu.exe
difftool.winmerge.cmd="c:/Program Files (x86)/winmerge/winmergeu.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
diff.guitool=kdiff3
difftool.kdiff3.path=c:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
```

It seems that the option "guitool" is overridden by git. Also the command line for winmerge seems incorrect.

Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is git config coming from?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17756753/456814).

Answer (score 1):

There reason was that my work laptop has a separate $HOME which is different to my local user account's home c:/users/account.

In summary I was editing the wrong .gitconfig