# Cannot find gitconfig file

Tags: git, linux-mint

I just started learning about Linux and Git. 
Im using Linux Mint. I have Git and emacs installed via apt-get.

Im using the following tutorial
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

it says that there are configuration files in three different places:

1. `/etc/gitconfig` file
2. `~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git/config` file
3. config file in the Git directory (that is, .git/config) of whatever repository you’re currently using.

I have just started with Git so assume that option 3) is not applicable

I checked both 1) and 2) - i just cannot locate the files anywhere

I googled this with no luck and did `sudo find . -name` in the root directory

Have no clue what is happening as when i run this

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

(i used my name surname above obviously)

it doesn't give me an error or anything - so where does it write this config data then?? where are these files?

Comment: Don't you see a `~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git/config` *after* typing a `git config --global` command?

Comment: no they are still not there, i configured user.name and user.email as shown above and the files still not there, so i dont even understand where this data is written...

Comment: Are you doing those command as yourself, or with a sudo in front of them (as root)? What does `echo $HOME` return?

Comment: I have just tried running them again with sudo and i can see the ~/.gitconfig in my home folder (echo $HOME) if i enable hidden files, my bad.. still learning Linux and have not got used to sudo yet. And though the ~/.gitconfig is almost empty (it should not be as per the tutorial) for some reasons at least i know where it is and how to access it. I will go on with tutorial now again, thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: the files might not exist before you add any config key but once you set your user.name the file should be created.

Comment: git config --global --edit       will edit that file for you

Comment: For the ```/etc/gitconfig``` file mystery, run As root ```git config --list –show-origin``` and the resulting file will be ```/root/.gitconfig```. Use ```nano``` to view it. I still wonder why i also got the mystery file too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As confirmed by the OP, any `git config --global` command will create/update `~/.gitconfig`.

But as it is an hidden file by default, you would need a `ls -alrt` to see it.
`git config --global -l` will list its content.

More generally, `git config --list --show-origin` shows all config files (and each line of the config data).
With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), you can [add a `--show-scope` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60286340/6309)

```
git config --list --show-origin --show-scope
```

That will also print the scope ("`local`", "`global`", etc) of all displayed config values.

---

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), confirm that `git config --show-scope` does show [worktree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309), in addition of local, global, system and command configs.

See [commit db7961e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db7961e6a69f648e8a1359c23830ff59d7341092) (07 Jun 2022) by [Glen Choo (`chooglen`)](https://github.com/chooglen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 21bb385](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21bb3851ee3c6fe945ed17c10b79dc153418fcdf), 13 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db7961e6a69f648e8a1359c23830ff59d7341092): document and test the '`worktree`' scope
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Glen Choo</sup>

> Test that "[`git config --show-scope`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/db7961e6a69f648e8a1359c23830ff59d7341092/Documentation/git-config.txt#L248)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---show-scope))</sup> shows the *worktree* scope, and add it to the list of scopes in `Documentation/git-config.txt`.
>
> "[`git config --help`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/db7961e6a69f648e8a1359c23830ff59d7341092/Documentation/git-config.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup> does not need to be updated because it already mentions `worktree`".

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/db7961e6a69f648e8a1359c23830ff59d7341092/Documentation/git-config.txt#L251):

> (worktree, local, global, system, command).

Comment: Thanks - that's correct and i also should've run the commands with sudo

Comment: @elnurcoot not sure about the `sudo`: that would execute them as `root`, which means a different `HOME`. Running them *without* `sudo` should put the `.gitconfig` in `$HOME` (do a `echo $HOME`, without `sudo`).

Comment: well echo $HOME with or without sudo returns the same directory for me, and the thing is - only after i did run the commands with sudo i could locate the ~/.gitocnfig file among the hidden files in my home directory..

Comment: @elnurcoot what does a `id -a` return?

Comment: uid=1000(elnur) gid=1000(elnur) groups=1000(elnur),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),110(sambashare)

Comment: @elnurcoot then `echo $HOME` should say `/home/elnur`, and your `.gitconfig` should be there. No sudo should be required.

Comment: that is correct but it was not there until i used sudo, that is the thing.. anyway - i will try to config other data without sudo and see if it works :)

Comment: if you use sudo it will create the .gitconfig file in the correct home directory just as sudo echo $HOME will print the correct home directory, the issue is that it will be owned by root and in the root group with rw-r--r-- priviledges

Comment: @VonC I tried `git config --global` and gave a `git config --global alias.aa="add --all"` but the .config file do not appear when `ls -alrt`. I am in the /home/user. It it visible when I list them like: `git config --global -l`

Comment: @lft93ryt try `git config -l --show-origin`: you will see what config is where.

Comment: For the ```/etc/gitconfig``` file mystery, run As root ```# git config --list –show-origin``` and the resulting file will be ```/root/.gitconfig```. use ```nano``` to view it. I still wonder why i also got the mystery file too.

Answer (score 9):

To find your global `.gitconfig` file:

1. Open your terminal or command prompt
2. Go to your root directory by typing `cd ~`
3. Once in your root folder type `ls -alrt`
4. You will see a `.gitconfig` file

   - To open your `.gitconfig` file type `open .gitconfig`

To find a particular repository's `.gitconfig` file:

1. Open your terminal or command prompt
2. Go to your *repository's* root directory by typing `cd path/to/repository-directory`
3. Once in your repository's root directory type `ls -alrt`
4. You will see a `.git` directory.  Type `cd .git`
5. Once in your repository's `git` directory type `ls -alrt`
6. You will see a `config` file

   - To open your repository's `.gitconfig` file type `open config`

Answer (score 1):

I got my config file by using `git config --system --list`

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following commands to discover the location of each Git config file:

```
sudo git -c core.editor=ls\ -al config --system --edit
sudo git -c core.editor=ls\ -al config --global --edit
sudo git -c core.editor=ls\ -al config --local --edit
sudo git -c core.editor=ls\ -al config --worktree --edit
```

You must be in a Git repo for the last two commands to work. The last command only works if you have [multiple Git worktrees](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Use-this-git-worktree-add-example-and-never-switch-branches-again) enabled.

Here's what it looks like [on Ubuntu](https://youtu.be/N0smppET4vA):

[image]

If you try and do git config on global or system you may need elevated rights, as the [Git config files](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Where-system-global-and-local-Windows-Git-config-files-are-saved) might be in the protected \root or \etc directories.

```
sudo git config --global user.name "cameronmcnz"
```

[image]

Comment: nothing worked for me :(   git --version
git version 2.34.1