# Why the .gitconfig always refer to /emacs?

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I'm new to git and I'm trying to upload my local directory to my Github. However, when I'm asked to set my account's default identity

```
  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

my terminal keeps giving me error:

```
error: could not lock config file C:/Users/marun/emacs/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

I downloaded emacs before but I deleted it since I seldom used it. How can I solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: How did you install `git`? Where is it in `PATH`?

Comment: @o11c Hi, my git path is "C:\Program Files\Git", path to git.exe should be "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:/Users/marun/emacs - that is probably set as you current home directory.

do the following to verify the theory.

```
echo $HOME
```

if it is the case, you need to reset your home directory: [how to](https://superuser.com/questions/1190364/how-to-set-home-directory-in-win10/1190369)

Comment: Thank you for answering! I check my home dir path, and it's "C:/Users/marun/"

Comment: Hi, my computer's home dir is "C:/Users/marun", but when I run the command in Git, it returns C:/Users/marun/emacs. How can I solve it? I think the solution in the post changes the home dir for the whole system?

Comment: how about that ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538639/cannot-find-gitconfig-file