# Windows-specific Git configuration settings; where are they set?

Tags: windows, git, git-config

I've read the Git documentation and [Where do the settings in my Git configuration come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756753/where-do-the-settings-in-my-git-configuration-come-from) and yet I still can't make sense of some of my settings.

I'm on Git 2.5.3 on Windows 10.  Here's the output of `git config -l`:

```
λ git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
user.name=Ben Collins
user.email=#redacted#
alias.sm=submodule
alias.br=branch
alias.co=checkout
alias.st=status
alias.rebuild=!git rm --cached -r . && git reset --hard
core.excludesfile=C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\gitignore_global.txt
core.editor=c:/Users/Benjamin/AppData/Local/atom/bin/atom.cmd
core.attributesfile=C:\Users\Benjamin\.gitattributes
push.default=simple
merge.tool=p4merge
mergetool.p4merge.cmd=p4merge.exe "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
mergetool.p4merge.path=C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
gui.encoding=utf-8
diff.guitool=p4merge
difftool.p4merge.path=C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
difftool.p4merge.cmd=p4merge.exe "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
mergetool.keepbackup=false
rerere.enabled=true
credential.helper=!'C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Roaming\GitCredStore\git-credential-winstore.exe'
filter.lfs.clean=git lfs clean %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git lfs smudge %f
filter.lfs.required=true
color.diff.whitespace=red reverse
```

What's bothersome is that the first twelve settings I cannot find *anywhere*.

```
C:\Program Files\Git
λ git config --system --list
fatal: unable to read config file 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
C:\Program Files\Git
λ git config --global --list
user.name=Ben Collins
user.email=#redacted#
alias.sm=submodule
alias.br=branch
alias.co=checkout
alias.st=status
alias.rebuild=!git rm --cached -r . && git reset --hard
core.excludesfile=C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\gitignore_global.txt
core.editor=c:/Users/Benjamin/AppData/Local/atom/bin/atom.cmd
core.attributesfile=C:\Users\Benjamin\.gitattributes
push.default=simple
merge.tool=p4merge
mergetool.p4merge.cmd=p4merge.exe "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
mergetool.p4merge.path=C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
gui.encoding=utf-8
diff.guitool=p4merge
difftool.p4merge.path=C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
difftool.p4merge.cmd=p4merge.exe "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
mergetool.keepbackup=false
rerere.enabled=true
credential.helper=!'C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Roaming\GitCredStore\git-credential-winstore.exe'
filter.lfs.clean=git lfs clean %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git lfs smudge %f
filter.lfs.required=true
color.diff.whitespace=red reverse
```

Also, when I try to unset one of the first twelve settings, it has no effect:

```
C:\Users\Benjamin\Projects\blah [master +0 ~1 -0]
λ git config --unset core.autocrlf
C:\Users\Benjamin\Projects\blah [master +0 ~1 -0]
λ git config core.autocrlf
true
C:\Users\Benjamin\Projects\Saddleback\cm-core [master +0 ~1 -0]
λ git config --unset-all core.autocrlf
C:\Users\Benjamin\Projects\Saddleback\cm-core [master +0 ~1 -0]
λ git config core.autocrlf
true
```

Are these first twelve settings hardcoded or platform-specific somehow?  How do I get control of them?

Comment: Did this help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114111/1190388 ?

Comment: @hjpotter92, no - this isn't about the global config (in $HOME/.gitconfig).  I've got a pretty good handle on that.  It seems that config settings basically get loaded in order, so something's getting loaded _before_ the global config, but the system config doesn't exist.  That and the fact that I can't unset those settings are the mystery.

Comment: Those may be Git's defaults for settings that have to be set to something. Instead of unsetting them, can you try to set them to something else, e.g. `git config core.autocrlf false`? If that works, and you then unset `core.autocrlf`, does it go back to `true`?

Comment: @Chris that's a great thought - but how do I set in a way that would prove something meaningful?  AFAIK, there's no `git config --mystery core.autocrlf false` ;-)

Comment: @BenCollins, I'm not sure what you mean. Wouldn't `git config --global core.autocrlf false` be meaningful, assuming it manages to change the value? And a subsequent `git config --global --unset core.autocrlf`, assuming it reverts you to your current state?

Comment: @Chris your question also highlights another interesting fact: if I set `core.autocrlf` to false in a local repository, it does actually show up in the list of configs - a second time.  It will resolve then, but that first entry is still there and still set to true, even when I override it.

Comment: @Chris yes, it's meaningful in the sense that I can override the value in a lower config, but the thrust of my question is that there is some higher, unnamed, untouchable config and I want to control it.

Comment: @BenCollins, understood. Does the `--edit` option [as suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10419350/354577) help?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  It opens the expected files, but I already knew about those.

Comment: In case it helps someone, I was able to find the location before finding this question with `git config --show-origin -l`

Comment: Not even ```git config --system core.autocrlf false``` in an Administrator Git Bash worked for me. I had to open the file in ProgramData and change it manually.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As [this commit](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/153328ba92ca6cf921d2272fa7e355603cbf71b7) explains, they've added another config location only for Windows, which is applied even before the `--system`:

> The file `/etc/gitconfig` can be used to store a system-wide default
>   configuration. On Windows, configuration can also be stored in
>   `C:\ProgramData\Git\config`; This file will be used also by
>   libgit2-based software.
>
> ...
>
> On Windows, as there is no central `/etc/` directory, there is yet
>   another config file, intended to contain settings for *all*
>   Git-related software running on the machine. Consequently, this config
>   file takes an even lower precedence than the `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`
>   file.

So I believe you can find those mystery settings in `C:\ProgramData\Git\config`.

---

From that commit I can see that `git config --system --list` should've shown you those settings, but it seems that the absence of `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig` file aborted the operation, which is probably a bug.

Comment: This answer does not have as near as how many upvotes it deserves :)
PS. I have the system gitconfig file but I don't see anything else on git config --system --list other than what is in that file (i don't see the well-hidden programdata file)

Comment: Note that that as of Git version 2.17, there appears to be no command-line facility to modify the settings in **C:\ProgramData\Git\config**. That file appears to be by default locked for Adminstrator privilege only, so what I had to do was execute _Run As Administrator_ context menu on my editor (Notepad++) shortcut, then edit it directly.

Comment: >> "This file will be used also by libgit2-based software." <<  It's really strange that settings from C:\ProgramData\Git\Config show up in the list, but don't show up when using any of the three switches: --system, --global, --local.

Comment: Since v2.23.0 this is no longer true. The location is now `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig`. See https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md

Comment: For me it's here for some reason... C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\etc\gitconfig

Comment: @KevinVictor, maybe you've installed git for windows only for your user account?

Answer (score 29):

In my version of git there is a **--show-origin** switch on the list command which gives away where the setting was applied from. I agree that it's confusing that there is no provided switch to access the windows configuration location inside ProgramData.

```
C:\Users\karlb>git --version
git version 2.11.0.windows.3

C:\Users\karlb>git config --list --show-origin
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.symlinks=false
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.fscache=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.diff=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.status=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.branch=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.interactive=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       help.format=html
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       rebase.autosquash=true
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    credential.helper=manager
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    difftool.usebuiltin=true
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    alias.lol=log --oneline --graph
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    alias.last=log -1 HEAD
file:C:/Users/karlb/.gitconfig  user.email=karl.horton@yahoo.com
file:C:/Users/karlb/.gitconfig  user.name=Karl Horton
```

Comment: It's really strange that settings from C:\ProgramData\Git\Config show up in the list, but don't show up when using any of the three switches: --system, --global, --local.

Comment: Kind of off topic, but the git program is missing the notion of "default" origin (that we can find for example in GNU make to know where a variable value comes from).
For example, we can't tell whether core.symlinks is true or false without having it explicitly defined in some config file. I suspect it's false by default only on Windows, but the listing should be made more friendly in this regard and provide a way to list *all* effective options. Even the --get command doesn't tell you.

Answer (score 2):

TIL a caveat concerning Git for Widows. I have `git version 2.17.1.windows.2`.

I tried to set a global `core.attributesfile` to override the line-ending attributes for `*.sh` files (I use *WSL*, and the present version becomes very unhappy when it tries to run shell scripts with DOS (CRLF) line endings. For Git on the Linux side, the following lines in `~\.gitattributes` solve the problem:

```
*.sln text eol=crlf
*.bat text eol=crlf
*.sh  text eol=cr
```

But using Git from Windows side (e.g. via Sourcetree GUI), for some repositories, I was still getting CRLF in *.sh files.

I found that in these repositories, `core.autocrlf=true`. Setting it to `input` solves the problem, and Git respects the global **gitattributes** now.

Comment: It would be worth digging in to this more; `.gitattributes` should override `core.autocrlf` *always*.

Comment: @EdwardThomson you mean, it could be posted as a bug report?

Comment: Maybe?  I think a Stack Overflow question might be a good place to start.  eg, does it behave differently in Sourcetree vs command-line?  What _exactly_ does your config file look like?  (For example, you mention `~\.gitattributes` which would not be a valid path to your home directory.)

Comment:  good questions! Here I only summarized the conclusions, and mentioned some details (e.g. Sourcetree) that may help someone who googles to solve her puzzle. Naturally I checked that command line and GUI produce same results. And the global gitattributes in Windows are set correctly through `git configure --global`.