# Where is core.autocrlf set in windows?

Tags: windows, git

I have git 2.6.2 installed in Windows 7.

I have `core.autocrlf` set to `False`. I'd like to know where that setting comes from. I have the following weird behavior:

```
> cd c:\
> git config --global --list | select-string autocrlf
> git config --system --list | select-string autocrlf
fatal: unable to read config file 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
> git config --list | select-string autocrlf

core.autocrlf=false
core.autocrlf=False


> git config core.autocrlf
False
```

So I have not set `core.autocrlf` in the global config. I have no system config. I am currently not in a git directory. Still, I get no less than *two* `core.autocrlf` settings.
Are they generated by the Git binary? (if so, why two settings?)

Comment: What is about `%HOME%\.config\git\config` ?

Comment: @kan interesting lead, I did have a `$env:HOME\.config` folder that I hadn't noticed, but I cannot find any git folder in it, or anything else remotely related to git.

Comment: I don't know then... Simpler just to pick `Process Monitor` and find accessed files.

Comment: My friend had the exact same issue and I was searching frantically to allow him to checkout my repository. He kept checking out shell scripts with `\r\n` so they wouldn't run. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in C:\ProgramData\Git\config.

And see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32849199/1121972) for more details (it's not just core.autocrlf that has a "phantom" value, there's more :) )