# Is there any other place for a git config setting other than global, system and local?

Tags: git

I'm on git version 2.8.3.windows.1 and a bit perplexed about where the `core.autocrlf` setting is actually being stored. In Git Extensions it shows as "not set", however I get the following when I query git config:

```
$ cd /c             <-- i.e. not a repo

$ git config --get core.autocrlf
false

$ git config --global --get core.autocrlf
(nothing)
$ git config --system --get core.autocrlf
(nothing)

$ git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=false
core.fscache=true
...

$ git config --system -l
credential.helper=manager

$ git config --global -l
core.editor="C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe" fileeditor
core.quotepath=false
color.ui=auto
... (not here either)

$ git config --local -l
fatal: unable to read config file '.git/config': No such file or directory
```

The .gitconfig file also doesn't have it

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[core]
        editor = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe\" fileeditor
        quotepath = false
```

So I get how GitExt is showing it as "not set", but I don't understand at all how `git config -l` is getting the value for `core.autocrlf`. And I can't seem to get rid of it to re-write it:

```
$ git config --unset core.autocrlf
fatal: not in a git directory

$ git config --unset --global core.autocrlf

$ git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=false
core.fscache=true
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows-specific Git configuration settings; where are they set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847697/windows-specific-git-configuration-settings-where-are-they-set)

Comment: Try `git config --show-origin -l`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Beginning with [Git for Windows 2.5.0](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.5.0.windows.1), there is a [system-wide Windows configuration area](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/104), so that [all Windows clients can interoperate](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/3475).

This new path is `%PROGRAMDATA%\Git\config`.

Despite the name, the "global" configuration area is not global on Windows, it is tied to a particular Git for Windows installation.