# git on windows: can't remove http.proxy setting

Tags: git

How do I remove that option on Windows?

I have already tried the following:

- git config --global -unset http.proxy
- git config -unset http.proxy
- deleted .gitconfig in my home folder
- re-installed git

I have tried everything but http.proxy is still listed in git config -l.

Where does git store its settings on windows? What kind of magic happens here behind the scenes? I have already spent half an hour.

**Update: Unfortunately I can't comment at** [Is there any other place for a git config setting other than global, system and local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326519/) **Anyways: the decision to make %PROGRAMDATA%\Git\config a system-wide configuration area on Windows is simply stupid, insane, confusing and idiosyncratic. Basically it means that we have some options that we cannot unset. To unset it we need to figure out that it turns out to be a %PROGRAMDATA%\Git\config file that should be edited manually.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git config --show-origin http.proxy
```

showed that the option came from C:/ProgramData/git/config.

I had absolutely know idea about that directory. Why is that? WTF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326519/is-there-any-other-place-for-a-git-config-setting-other-than-global-system-and/38328161#38328161