# Unable to download artifact from azure repo for release pipeline in azure devops server

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, tfs, azure-devops

Unable to download artifact from azure repo for release pipeline in azure devops server

trying to create a release pipeline in azure devops server/TFS, where i kept deplpyment yamls in azure repo, All most died trying all possible solution available

```
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4023196Z ##[debug]Evaluating: SucceededNode()
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4028590Z ##[debug]Evaluating SucceededNode:
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4062985Z ##[debug]=> True
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4084197Z ##[debug]Result: True
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4139706Z ##[section]Starting: Download Artifacts
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4228690Z Creating artifacts directory: C:\application2_agent\_work\r1\a
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4312837Z Created artifacts directory: C:\application2_agent\_work\r1\a
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4312949Z Downloading artifact
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4322919Z Starting artifacts download...
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4333439Z Downloading linked artifact application-ebx-acc-repo of type TFGit...
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4357233Z Ensuring artifact folder C:\application2_agent\_work\r1\a\application-ebx-acc-repo exists and is clean.
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4588608Z Syncing repository: 18c91948-ed72-4057-8f2f-3dcf1cf9eb97 (Git)
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4622920Z Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'git.exe'.
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4628360Z ##[debug]Path: 'C:\application2_agent\externals\git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\tsiadm\Downloads;C:\Program Files\Docker;F:\agentutility\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin;C:\Users\admjawedt02\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps'
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4649646Z ##[debug]Get git version.
2021-02-18T01:29:00.4665743Z ##[command]git version
2021-02-18T01:29:00.5619545Z git version 2.18.0.windows.1
2021-02-18T01:29:00.5642621Z ##[debug]Detect git version: 2.18.0.
2021-02-18T01:29:00.5726643Z ##[debug]Get git-lfs version.
2021-02-18T01:29:00.5727602Z ##[command]git lfs version
2021-02-18T01:29:00.7459095Z git-lfs/2.12.1 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.14.10; git 85b28e06)
2021-02-18T01:29:00.7460870Z ##[debug]Detect git-lfs version: '2.12.1'.
2021-02-18T01:29:00.7464636Z ##[debug]Set git useragent to: git/2.18.0 (vsts-agent-git/2.144.2).
2021-02-18T01:29:00.7500381Z ##[debug]Checking if the repo on C:\application2_agent\_work\r1\a\application-ebx-acc-repo matches the expected repository origin URL. expected Url: https://azdevops.demo.net/DefaultCollection/Datsoul/_git/Datsoul
2021-02-18T01:29:00.7501113Z ##[debug]Repository is not found since '.git' directory does not exist under. C:\application2_agent\_work\r1\a\application-ebx-acc-repo
2021-02-18T01:29:00.7526034Z ##[debug]Init git repository at: C:\application2_agent\_work\r1\a\application-ebx-acc-repo.
2021-02-18T01:29:00.7540690Z ##[command]git init "C:\application2_agent\_work\r1\a\application-ebx-acc-repo"
2021-02-18T01:29:00.8541126Z Initialized empty Git repository in C:/application2_agent/_work/r1/a/application-ebx-acc-repo/.git/
2021-02-18T01:29:00.8615931Z ##[debug]Add git remote: origin to url: https://azdevops.demo.net/DefaultCollection/Datsoul/_git/Datsoul for repository under: C:\application2_agent\_work\r1\a\application-ebx-acc-repo.
2021-02-18T01:29:00.8616101Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://azdevops.demo.net/DefaultCollection/Datsoul/_git/Datsoul
2021-02-18T01:29:00.9703602Z ##[debug]Disable git auto garbage collection.
2021-02-18T01:29:00.9703752Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2021-02-18T01:29:01.0556858Z ##[debug]Checking git config http.https://azdevops.demo.net/DefaultCollection/Datsoul/_git/Datsoul.extraheader exist or not
2021-02-18T01:29:01.0557012Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://azdevops.demo.net/DefaultCollection/Datsoul/_git/Datsoul.extraheader
2021-02-18T01:29:01.1484525Z ##[debug]Checking git config http.proxy exist or not
2021-02-18T01:29:01.1484704Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2021-02-18T01:29:01.2489712Z ##[debug]Remove any proxy setting from git config.
2021-02-18T01:29:01.2524557Z ##[debug]Unset git config --unset-all http.proxy
2021-02-18T01:29:01.2524692Z ##[command]git config --unset-all http.proxy
2021-02-18T01:29:01.3521192Z ##[warning]Unable to remove "http.proxy" from the git config. To remove the credential, execute "git config --unset-all http.proxy" from the repository root "http.proxy".
2021-02-18T01:29:01.3559540Z ##[debug]Fetch git repository at: C:\application2_agent\_work\r1\a\application-ebx-acc-repo remote: origin.
2021-02-18T01:29:01.3580216Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2021-02-18T01:29:01.5248741Z fatal: could not read Password for 'http://satyam@xyz.net@10.220.129.49:80': terminal prompts disabled
2021-02-18T01:29:01.5514915Z An error occurred during download: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.ArtifactDownloadException: Unexpected error occurred while downloading artifacts ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.TfsGitArtifact.DownloadAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ArtifactDefinition artifactDefinition, String downloadFolderPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.TfsGitArtifact.DownloadAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ArtifactDefinition artifactDefinition, String downloadFolderPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifacts(IExecutionContext executionContext, IList`1 agentArtifactDefinitions, String artifactsWorkingFolder)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifactsAndCommitsAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, Object data)
2021-02-18T01:29:01.5566770Z ##[error]Unexpected error occurred while downloading artifacts
2021-02-18T01:29:01.5570926Z ##[debug]Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.ArtifactDownloadException: Unexpected error occurred while downloading artifacts ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.TfsGitArtifact.DownloadAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ArtifactDefinition artifactDefinition, String downloadFolderPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2021-02-18T01:29:01.5574268Z ##[section]Finishing: Download Artifacts
```

Comment: removed some of the logs due to size constrain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSTS Git Fetch Failed with exit code: 128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51547858/vsts-git-fetch-failed-with-exit-code-128)

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me know if it helps you to fix this issue.

Comment: Yes we have re configured a fresh self hosted agent and then it started working

Comment: Great to hear it was fixed. You can share out your solution, in case other community users encounter this  issue.

Answer (score 0):

> ##[warning]Unable to remove "http.proxy" from the git config. To remove the credential...
>
> fatal: could not read Password for 'http://satyam@xyz.net@10.220.129.49:80': terminal prompts disabled

From above error, it seemed that it was caused by the git proxy settings on your agent machine. The git proxy setting failed to be removed, and it prompted to ask for proxy password.

You can try logging into your agent machine and run below command locally to remove any proxy setting from git config.

`git config --unset-all http.proxy`

**And Then** you also need to check the system-wide configuration area on Windows which is the `%PROGRAMDATA%\Git\config` file.  You need to manually edit this config file to unset the proxy settings.

You can run command `git config --show-origin http.proxy` to get the system-wide configuration area. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326519/is-there-any-other-place-for-a-git-config-setting-other-than-global-system-and/38328161#38328161).

After the proxy setting is removed from git config. You can have a try running your pipeline again.

Answer (score -1):

Limit job authorization scope to current project
Azure Pipelines provides two Limit job authorization scope to current project settings:

Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines - This setting applies to YAML pipelines and classic build pipelines. This setting does not apply to classic release pipelines.
Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines - This setting applies to classic release pipelines only.