# Why are there two different lines with core.autocrlf output with "git config -l"?

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

I'm trying to set `core.autocrlf=true`. But after executing `git config --global core.autocrlf true` the output of `git config -l` shows both these lines

```
core.autocrlf=false
... other settings ...
core.autocrlf=true
```

Why is this, and how can I ensure that `autocrlf` gets properly set to `true`?

Comment: Your system/local config has it set to false. Check `repo/.git/config`. If the property isn't there, then `/etc/gitconfig` has this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can know more with Git 2.8+:

```
git config -l --show-origin
```

That will give you a better idea from where those settings come from.
Local config override global settings which overrides system settings.

See a concrete example in "[Where do the settings in my Git configuration come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35670933/6309)".

[Xavi Montero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315009/xavi-montero) points out to the Pro Book "[Getting Started - First-Time Git Setup](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)" which mentions:

> If you are using version 2.x or later of Git for Windows, there is *also* a **system-level** config file at
>
> - `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Git\config` on Windows XP, and
> - in `C:\ProgramData\Git\config` on Windows Vista and newer.
>
> This config file can only be changed by `git config -f <file>` as an admin.

---

On Windows 10, [Jon R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12508260/jon-r) reports the issue was in `C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig`.

Comment: Thanks! In Windows, I got those two `autocrlf` settings too; and I was turning mad as the `--show-origin` revealed me that the setting was in `file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"`. That file adds a number of settings that did **not** show up neither in `--system`, nor `--global`, nor `--local` standardized namespaces. I'll open a question to ask why this happens...

Comment: No question needed. In fact, it is documented in the `v2` documentation here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup which says "there is also a system-level config file at C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Git\config on Windows XP, and in C:\ProgramData\Git\config on Windows Vista and newer. This config file can only be changed by git config -f <file> as an admin." - CAUTION to users from Spain: When googling for [git config], it takes to https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Empezando-Configurando-Git-por-primera-vez which does not reflect that.

Comment: @XaviMontero Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: In my case (Windows 10) the bogus config was in C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig

Comment: @JonR Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.