# Git Config core.autocrlf overwrite

Tags: git

I'm trying to set the `autocrlf` property to `false`. For some reason I currently having 3 such entries and I'm assuming one of them overwrites the others.
Running `git config -l` returns a list with 3 `autocrlf` entries, one of them `true`, 2 of them `false`
[image]

Running `git config --global -l` returns a list with one `autocrlf` entry set to `false`
[image]

Running `git config --local-l` returns a list with one `autocrlf` entry set to `false`
[image]

Running `git config --system -l` returns an error
[image]

Somewhere there is a file maybe that contains the true setting. How can I find this file? Could the error I'm getting for the system config have something to do with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With git version 2.8 onwards, you can simply use:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

You will see which config is set where.

Also, see "[Where do the settings in my Git configuration come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35670933/6309)"

It is also possible that the third entry lives in c:\Users\All Users\git\config but the output of the above command should remove the guesswork.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With the new version i managed to find out that the problematic file was located in c:\ProgramData\Git\config.

Comment: Great. Which file was the third entry coming from?

Comment: Posted a new asnwer to explain the source of the problem and a solution. I will select your answer as the correct one because thats the right way to get to the core of the problem. Thanks again. Saved me a lot of headaches:)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the the problematic property was set by the windows installer. Specifically this page:
[image]

When selecting the first option the autoclrf is set to true in you **c:\ProgramData\Git\config** file. Don't know how you can change this using a console command, like git config --"which_one?" core.autocrlf false. As a workaround simply edit the file.