# Unable to remove http.proxy setting inside git system repository (config file)

Tags: git

I can't find a way to remove the http.proxy setting from the system config file.

My research concluded that there is a single `system` config file located at %Program Files%\Git\mingw64\etc\ but it does not have the proxy setting. However, when I open the repository setting inside VS, the http.proxy setting is still set.

I've used all the following codes, but it still http.proxy setting is still set  under the repository settings for the system variable:

I've attempted the following:

1. `git config --unset http.proxy`
2. `git config --global --unset http.proxy`
3. `git config --system --unset http.proxy`
4. I've deleted the config file under the %Program Files%\Git\mingw64\etc

Is there any other locations on the machine where the system config file is located?

I remember when I initially trying to setup the http.proxy setting, I modified the file manually. But I can't seem to remember which file I actually modified or the location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do the settings in my Git configuration come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756753/where-do-the-settings-in-my-git-configuration-come-from)

Answer (score 0):

There is a config file in every repository. So go to your repo folder.

```
vim .git/config
```

There you should find alle the settings for the repository. So `system` and `global` read the normal configuration files. So perhaps there is an entry in the repository you don't want to.

Comment: is there a specific setting inside the local git file that prevents the repo from reading the normal system and global config files?

Answer (score 0):

After updating VS to the newest version (15.8.0), the issue was resolved.