# Why does git not recognize me when I create a branch?

Tags: git, github

When I create a branch, it doesn't recognize my git name but rather `MV WAG SCM`. See image below.

[image: git]

`git config --list` yields:

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
push.default=current
pull.default=current
pull.rebase=true
user.email="myname@gmail.com" -> This is correct
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
....items related to remote branches
username.user=myUserName -> This is correct
username.email="myname@gmail.com" -> This is correct
```

I also cannot push any changes... What's wrong?

Comment: Could you show the "git commit..." you ran and the output of "git config --list"?

Comment: credential.helper=osxkeychain
    push.default=current
    pull.default=current
    pull.rebase=true
    user.email="myname@gmail.com" -> This is correct
    core.repositoryformatversion=0
    core.filemode=true
    core.bare=false
    core.logallrefupdates=true
    core.ignorecase=true
    core.precomposeunicode=true
    ....items related to remote branches
    username.user=myUserName -> This is correct
    username.email="myname@gmail.com" -> This is correct

Comment: I added it to the details

Comment: Try running `git config user.name "your name"` or committing with --author "your name"

Comment: are you running `git config --list` inside the actual directory of the project? Otherwise you're just pulling your global git config. Does everything look ok in the `.git/config` file that's in your project directory? Were you able to push to GitHub with your proper email + username in the past? What do you see when you run `git log` in the project directory?

Comment: Is this the case for every commit? Does the incorrect name appear locally when you run `git log` or is it only a Github problem?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756753/where-do-the-settings-in-my-git-configuration-come-from

Answer (score 5):

There are a bunch of important things to keep in mind here.  Here are the top two:

- Git is *distributed*, meaning, there are a lot of different computers involved. Each one can have its own idea of what's what.
- GitHub is not Git!  GitHub is a hosting company that offers a Git service.  They hide the actual Git implementation with a fancy interface.  That fancy interface is not part of Git, and a lot of it barely uses Git at all.

Now, the image snippet you're showing is from GitHub.  So it's showing you what *GitHub* says, which has, quite literally, nothing at all to do with anything you can set *now* in your own Git repository.  It *may* have something to do with something you had set earlier—earlier today, or yesterday, or whenever—in your Git repository.

> `git config --list` yields ...

These are settings you have set on *your* computer.  You can change them at any time.

Note that there are two (or more) different places for your personal settings.  Git calls these `--global` and `--local`.  Git 2.20 and 2.21 added one new one, `--worktree`, which you are probably not using.  Use `git config --list --show-origin` to see which place stores which setting.

> ....items related to remote branches
>
> ```
> username.user=myUserName -> This is correct
> username.email="myname@gmail.com" -> This is correct
> ```

These may be *correct*, but I cannot find anything that uses a `username.user` or `username.email` setting.  (There might be something, but Git allows you to set anything to anything without complaint. If you were supposed to set, for instance, `zaphod.beeblebrox=heads:2` for some piece of software, but accidentally ran `git config hoopy.frood towel` instead, Git would have no complaints about this—neither mean anything to *Git*.)

> ```
> push.default=current
> pull.default=current
> ```

The first one is meaningful, but in general, most people should leave the default `push.default` setting of `simple` in place.  The second has no meaning.

> ```
> user.email="myname@gmail.com"
> ```

This one is no doubt correct.  The remaining one that's *missing* from the list you quoted, though, is `user.name`.

Now, it's important to realize that `user.name` and `user.email` are only used by your Git *when you use your Git to create a new commit*.  At that time—at the time you make the commit—Git reads these two settings.  Whatever is in them, goes into the new commit.  The new commit, once made, is frozen for all time.  You can make *other* commits that have *different* user-name and/or email settings, and if the commit you just made had the wrong settings, you probably *should* make another commit.  But any commit that you did make that has the *wrong* stuff in it, has that wrong stuff in it *forever*.

That's not so bad!  You don't have to keep using a wrong commit at all.  If you made a wrong commit, you can, for instance, change things and run `git commit --amend` to throw out the wrong commit and replace it with a better one.  The thrown-out one remains in your repository, but it's shoved out of the way, where you—and everyone else—can't see it, and it won't be sent on to some other Git when you run `git push`.  And you can fix more than just the last commit, using `git rebase -i --reset-author`, for instance.  Like `--amend` it doesn't *change* any commits; instead, it makes new-and-improved ones, and stops using the old-and-lousy ones.<sup>1</sup>

The user name and email you set in your configuration, that got copied into any commit you made already, show up when you run `git log`.  Those two items—the user name and email—can be *anything you want*.  Nobody and nothing can stop you from using other people's name(s) and email address(es) here.  These commits are going into *your* repository, on *your* computer, and you can do whatever you want with your own computer.

But now that you *have* made some new commits, now you may want to have your Git *send* those new commits to some other Git repository.  That other Git repository can be hosted anywhere, including, perhaps, on GitHub.  If you *do* send a new commit to GitHub, they're not just going to believe that you are Barack Obama or whoever.  So, now you have to *authenticate* yourself.  This is where this setting *may* come into play:

> ```
> credential.helper=osxkeychain
> ```

If you connect to GitHub via https, Git will need to use a credential helper, and this tells it which one to use.  If you connect to GitHub via ssh, ssh has its own independent mechanisms; this `credential.helper` setting will be ignored.

> I also cannot push any changes... What's wrong?

Probably, one or both of two things:

- Your attempt to authenticate to GitHub is failing: they don't believe you are who you claim to be.
- Or, they *do* believe you are who you claim to be, but that person does not have permission to push.

From what you've posted here, we cannot tell which of these is the case.  But the error message that GitHub delivers back to your Git, and your Git passes on to you, *will* tell you which of these is the case (or whether it's some less-obvious possibility).  So, find out how you're authenticating (or failing to authenticate), and if that's succeeding, whether you have permission to push.  Correct whichever of these is a problem (perhaps both).

Once you get past all of these issues, the last stumbling block is this: *Git pushes commits*.  Remember that we said, earlier, that all commits are frozen in time forever.  When your Git goes to send their Git a commit, your Git hands over the hash ID—the unique name that goes with *that* commit, and *only* that commit; no other commit has that hash-ID-name—and, if they don't already have that commit, your Git hands over everything they need so that they can have that commit too.

So, after all of this crazy Rube-Goldberg-esque machinery has conveyed your commit(s) to the Git repository stored on GitHub, they will have some new set of commits—maybe just one commit, maybe a whole string of them—that they did not have before.  Your Git will, in the end, ask their Git to set one of *their* branch names, or create a new branch name, to remember the last of those commits.<sup>2</sup>  GitHub then takes the *email address* stored in these frozen-forever commits, and *looks them up* in a giant database.

The database is how *GitHub* (not Git!) decides *who* made a commit.  It's up to GitHub and their database to keep this translation working.  They have a couple of different fancy schemes for this; see, e.g., https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-happens-when-i-change-my-username and related articles.  They also have ways to control which email address(es) they will consider to be "you" when they see those email addresses in existing, frozen commits.

**If you work with command-line Git, in your own repository on your own computer, you see what Git stored.  If you work with the GitHub web interface, you see what GitHub translates *to*, from what Git stored.  The actual storage is in the commits themselves, so until you have commits stored in a Git repository on GitHub, GitHub can't do any translating.**

---

<sup>1</sup>If you *already* sent a wrong commit on to some other Git by running `git push`, *then* you have a problem.  It's not necessarily a big problem, but it's good to be pretty sure you have the right commits before you run `git push`.  It's much easier to throw away bad commits in favor of improved replacement commits *before* you've scattered those bad commits to millions of other Git clones all over the universe ... or even just one other Git clone hosted at GitHub, or whatever.  The real point here, though, is that you can't *change* a commit, you can only replace it with a new-and-improved commit.  If you do that before anyone else ever sees anything, *they* will never know that you had a wrong commit!

<sup>2</sup>The last commit remembers hash ID of the one before it, automatically.  That's the *parent* of the last commit.  The parent commit remembers *its* parent, which remembers another parent, and so on—so from the *end*, Git can work backwards to the beginning.  This backwards-looking chain *is* the history in the repository!  The act of starting at the end, showing a commit, and walking back to its parent, is how you, or anyone else, can *view* the history.  The commits, with their relationships—parent, child, sibling, or unrelated at all—determine the history stored in the repository.  The *branch names* just serve as a way to *find* the *last* commits.

Comment: `zaphod.beeblebrox=heads:2` is an heresy. Everyone on zaphod knows that beeblebrox's head value is binary.

Comment: @RomainValeri 