# Double Username on Github

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm making changes to my repo's on Github but it says that the commits are made by `aronweston` when my username is `aronrweston`.

My main user https://github.com/aronrweston
Second mystery username: https://github.com/aronweston

Every time I make commits through my IDE, it commits as the second username.

Is this normal? It doesn't say that I have made any commits on my account when I have?

Comment: Can you post the output of `git config user.name`?

Comment: My main username, `aronrweston`

Comment: And if you cd into the local repository that is giving you issues and you do `git config --local user.name` what does it say?

Comment: The same checks for `user.email`

Comment: It shows nothing, just another empty line. But when I do `git config -l --local` it doesn't show a username or email. Is it supposed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the commit can be made (authored) by `xxx` without GitHub having an account https://github.com/xxx.

Authorship (`git config user.name`) is not equal to authentication (the GitHub account at https://github.com/xxx)

Second, to avoid any error, make sure your `git config -l --show-origin --show-scope` executed in your local repository has not "local" `user.name`, only one global `user.name`.

That way, you won't have to deal with multiple authors.
As commented, the same applies for `user.email`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm still stuck. I get `unknown option show-scope` when entering `git config -l --show-origin --show-scope`. However, `git config -l --show-origin` shows the correct `user.name` and `user.email`

Comment: @aron_weston `--show-scope` is from Git 2.26 (Q1 2020): https://stackoverflow.com/a/60286340/6309, so it is a good idea to upgrade Git, if possible. What file is associated with your `user.name`? One local to your repository, or one global, set in your profile path? (`~/.gitconfig`)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, running 2.29.2 now. Only the one set of `user.name` and `user.email` set to global in the `~/.gitconfig` path. There's no local.

Comment: @aron_weston That is good. You want only one place where those settings are defined.